# I get an error when trying to create a XERO APP: Failed to create app #07D4

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to create my first Xero app and I am getting a `#07D4 error "Failed to create app"` and I can't find documentation on this type of error on the Xero documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I work on the team that owns this and this problem is linked to a production incident that is underway. You can follow the updates here: https://status.developer.xero.com/incidents/v532f59qpfp5

We keep that StatusPage up to date with any running incidents. Apologies for the inconvenience.